# flutter, How to copy subranges of multi-step input

Tags: flutter, copy, textfield

When copying text from TextField, how should I copy the subrange in case of multi-step input (composing mode)?

For example, the following code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomeWidget());
  }
}

class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController _controller1 = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _focusNode1 = FocusNode();
  TextEditingController _controller2 = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _focusNode2 = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                focusNode: _focusNode1,
                controller: _controller1,
              ),
              TextField(
                focusNode: _focusNode2,
                controller: _controller2,
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("copy text"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if(_focusNode1.hasFocus) {
                      _controller2.text = _controller1.text;
                      _focusNode1.unfocus();
                      _focusNode2.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                      _controller1.text = _controller2.text;
                      _focusNode2.unfocus();
                      _focusNode1.requestFocus();
                    }
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(SampleWidget());
}
```

It is possible to copy text in English "abcd" in TextField.

[image]

but in case of multi-step input(composing mode), copying text is not possible.

Korean is a combinatorial language, that means characters such as '가', '구', and '거' can be written ordinarily 'ㄱ' + ‘ㅏ’, ‘ㄱ’+ ‘ㅜ’ and ‘ㄱ’ + ‘ㅓ’.

However, the code moves to the next character range just after 'ㄱ'.
(I want the code to keep until ‘ㄱ’ is combined with ‘ㅏ’)

[image]

How can I solve this problem?